# Get node id for page which is set for 403 and 404

Tags: 7, configuration

I want to get the node number (nid) for the node which is set for 403 and 404 pages in drupal configuration system.
Can you please help me for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
variable_get('site_403');
variable_get('site_404');
```

It will return a string like "node/1", then you just have to parse this string to get back the node ID.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention if this is via code or just admin screens. Through the admin screens you can view/edit what page is set for the 403 and 404 pages:

"Configuration > System > Site information"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for answering this, I tried this

```
global $conf;
print_r($conf['site_403']);
```

It is working fine.